# Unable to get friends likes using facebook graph api

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble getting a user's friends' likes. 
 I can get gender, name and birthday, but not television, movies, music,books, games and likes.

```
me/friends?fields=gender,name,birthday,television,movies,music,books,games,likes&uid={USERID}
```

It works when I am logged onto my account, but not when one of my friends accounts.

Why is that? I'm pretty sure that I have the correct permissions.

Comment: Do you have `friends_likes` permission?

Comment: @Igy yes i do, i just double checked

Comment: And none of that user's friends likes are returned? or your likes are not returned? Are you sure it isn't due to privacy settings of the person whose likes you're trying to access?

Comment: @Igy looked up the same 5 people logged on 3 different accounts,including mine. 

On my account, it returns everything without error. With the other two accounts it does not. Except for when they look at my account.

Comment: @Igy have no problem getting the gender, name or birthday for other users friends. Just not what the users' friend likes (t television, movies, music,books, games and likes)

Comment: The parameter uid not is required, you can use only with: `me/friends?fields=gender,name,birthday,television,movies,music,books,games,likes`

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz I need to get a specific persons likes, not all users' friends infromation

Comment: well, first, you need have an Access token for this operation
you can try also with fql, is a better option.

Comment: So I ask again, **Are you sure it isn't due to privacy settings of the person whose likes you're trying to access?** - If it's a specific person's likes you're trying access, using the access token of one of their friends, do that user's privacy settings allow apps their friends use to access their likes?

Comment: What you need to do now is 1. loggedin as these two accounts on www.facebook.com/PROBLEM_USER_ID/tv to check these two users+yourself(3 users) able to see or not. 2. If there's no different between 3 users(all can see the tv likes), do these step:
Assume your app name is MY_APP, then make sure PROBLEM_USER_ID had installed MY_APP. And make sure the PROBLEM_USER_ID tick the "Activities, interests, things I like" field on https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share 3. And make sure you are using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check "friends_likes"